# Best way to "stream" Google Pub/Sub messages directly to frontend? Server-sent events?

Tags: java, servlets, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events, google-cloud-pubsub

First things first: My Pub/Sub knowledge is basic, my server-sent event knowledge even below that.

What I am wondering is how to build a single page application (with 1-10 concurrent users, something small and internal) that can (near-)instantly show (not write just read) Pub/Sub messages as they are coming in. I've so far been able to botch together a Java Servlet that starts an asynchronous pull and writes to an EventSource in the frontend, however I'm asking myself whether that is complete nonsense* to begin with and whether there is something else out there that I should be looking into (I guess I'm asking for the right keywords).

* it works 1/10 times and only locally right now.

Any CONSTRUCTIVE tips are appreciated.

Comment: You should use Web Sockets.

Comment: Sounds like you want Firebase. Cloud Pub/Sub is not made for sending messages to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer here really depends on the use case. One thing that is certain is that the client code itself calling into Cloud Pub/Sub would not be the right thing to do. Cloud Pub/Sub is not designed to scale in the number of subscriptions, both per topic and per project; the [limit on each of these is 10,000](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits).

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) would be a good candidate to use here. It is designed to deliver messages to end users, including those accessing a web page. Depending on the original producer of the messages, Cloud Pub/Sub may be used to send messages from one server to another and these messages may ultimately be fed to Firebase.

Some design questions to consider would be:

1. Do all users need to see all messages or does each need to see a subset of messages?
2. What is the original source of the messages? Are they already in Cloud Pub/Sub and now they need to be distributed to the individual users or are other transport layers being considered?
3. If the messages are in Cloud Pub/Sub, how many frontend servers will you have? If it's more than one, then you'll need to have a subscription per server in order for all instances to receive the full feed of messages that are then sent on to users via other means.